# CSS background overlay only apply to the image

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

I have this code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .body{
      background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/13760434/pexels-photo-13760434.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1") rgba(23, 27, 45, 0.8);
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-blend-mode: overlay;
   
    }
    .main{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;

     
    }
    .card{
      background-color: white;
      padding: 1rem;
     
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body class="body">
  <main class="main">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Card 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Card 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Card 3</h1>
    </div>
  </main>
  
</body>
</html>
```

My goal was to apply background image repeat to x axis and adding a overlay on top of that image. If you run this code and view results in full screen, you will see after the image also the overlay part appied. I think the reason is I added image to the body tag. I still want add the image to the body tag and overlay only to the image. It should not exceed the image.

[image]

Right after the image I want to see the normal background color white. How do I achive this in CSS?

Comment: the background of the body is not only the images. Utilize pseudo-elements that you fill with the background images and apply the filter to that pseudo-elements.

Comment: @tacoshy can you show me how to do this?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://css-tricks.com/apply-a-filter-to-a-background-image/